# How to detect whether the given point is on particular menu or not

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I want to detect whether the given point is on particular menu or not.

I tried to do this by following code, but it gives error of null reference.

(Error - java.lang.NullPointerException)

```
    // p : is point
    // f : is flag (boolean variable)
    for (Menu menu : menuBarMain.getMenus()) {
        Node m = menu.getGraphic();
        if (m.contains(m.screenToLocal(p))) {
            f = true;
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: at what line are you getting the null pointer exception ?

Comment: it returns node m as null, error at if (m.contains(m.screenToLocal(p))) {

Comment: Not every menu has a `graphic`. The graphic is some content you include in addition to the menu's text, e.g. a floppy disk image for a save menu item...

Comment: It works for tab header

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`graphic` property](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/MenuItem.html#graphicProperty) just is some content that is shown in addition to the text of the menu. This may e.g. be a floppy disk for a save menu. This property is `null` in case there is no such content. This results in your exception.

You could find out, if one of the [`MenuButton`s](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/MenuButton.html) in a `MenuBar` contains the node using [`lookupAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#lookupAll-java.lang.String-) to find the nodes (provided the layout has already been performed on the `MenuBar`):

```
for (Node menu : menuBarMain.lookupAll(".menu")) {
    if (menu.contains(menu.screenToLocal(p))) {
        f = true;
        break;
    }
}
```